# Converting a message from one PGP key to another PGP key

Tags: pgp

I have a message $M$ that is encrypted using a public key $P_1$. I lost the associated private key $p_1$. I have another public/private key pair $(P_2, p_2)$. Is it possible to "translate" the encrypted message using public key $P_1$ to a message that is encrypted using public key $P_2$ (this way I can decrypt the message using private key $p_2$)?

Answer (score 4):

No - If you could do this, what would prevent someone else from doing the same thing with their private key?

Comment: It would be an interesting property to be able to reencrypt without the private key when using *related* keypairs as you can have in PGP, but I'm pretty sure that this is not a property of the current algorithms used.